# Plot factor proportion in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
     edu   default 
1    1      0    
2    3      1    
3    1      1   
4    1      0   
5    2      1   
6    2      0   
...
```

and I could make a plot using R :

```
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = edu, fill = default)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = 'Education') +
  theme_excel()
```

[image]

Instead of counts of **1**s and **0**s in *default*, I want to plot the proportion of **1**s like this:

[image]

I calculated the proportion separately, store the results in another data frame and made this plot.

My question is: Is there a compact way that I could do this in a single `ggplot()` command like I did in the previous plot?

Update:
I forgot to mention that the data type of `default` is **factor**. So applying `mean` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

We recall that the proportion of 1's in a binary vector is simply its mean. The way to plot mean values per `x` in `ggplot` is using the `stat_summary` function. So we get:

```
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = edu, y = default)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', geom = 'bar')
```

Or:

```
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = edu, y = default)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'summary')               #include fun.y = 'mean' to avoid the message
```

Both give:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that the data type of `default` is **factor**. So applying `mean` does not work.

Comment: Use `y = as.numeric(default) - 1` or `y = as.numeric(as.character(default))`.

Comment: That will do. But what if, instead of **1**s and **0**s, I have **Y**s and **N**s in that column?

Comment: And what if I have more than 2 levels, and I want to plot the proportion of a single level?

Comment: Use `y = default == "my_required_level"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148484/discussion-between-sidney-and-axeman).

Comment: It works as `y = as.numeric(default == "my_required_level")`